# From Blender 3D to Android studio

Tags: android, blender

Is there any possibility to export to Android models and animations created in Blender 3D?
I have already searched in the net, but didn't find anything that could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just export your meshes as Wavefront (**.obj**) files end import them into your app through a 3D library.
Some libraries can also load Collada (**.dae**), 3D Studio (**.3ds**) or other common 3D file formats.

I won't provide any link, because you must get the taste of choosing among multiple results.
Try, fail, try another one which is lighter/easier or better fits your needs.
And links are subject to premature death.

All of the aforementioned file formats can be exported by Blender.
Just set up the required import/export plugins in the preferences.

You got the gist of how to proceed.
Hope it's helpful for someone.
Including my future self.